# Eigen: dividing a vector by a scalar in two steps works but not in one step

Tags: c++, eigen

So I'm trying to implement [Power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) to find the greatest eigenvalue and corresponding eigenvector in C++. I'm using the Eigen library. The weird thing is that, when I divide a vector by a scalar in a single line (marked in line (1)), it throws an error, and is as helpful as C++ errors can be:

```
No viable conversion from 'typename internal::enable_if<true, const CwiseBinaryOp<internal::scalar_quotient_op<typename internal::traits<Product<Product<Transpose<Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >, Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1>, 0>, Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 0> >::Scalar, typename internal::promote_scalar_arg<Scalar, double, (Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Scalar, double, Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<Scalar, double> > >::value)>::type>, const Product<Product<Transpose<Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >, Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1>, 0>, Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 0>, const typename internal::plain_constant_type<Product<Product<Transpose<Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >, Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1>, 0>, Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 0>, typename internal::promote_scalar_arg<Scalar, double, (Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Scalar, double, Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<Scalar, double> > >::value)>::type>::type> >::type'
(aka 'const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<double, double>, const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1>, 0>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 0>, const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1> > >')
to 'double'
```

but when I do it in two steps (marked in line (2)), everything is fine and no errors are thrown. So I find it very weird that Eigen can't do division by scalars in a single step. What is happening here, why it fails when I do it on a single line?

```
pair<double, Vector> power_iteration(const Matrix& X, unsigned num_iter, double eps)
{
    Vector b = Vector::Random(X.cols());
    b.normalize();
    Vector b_old;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++){
        b_old =b;
        b = X*b_old;
        b.normalize();
        double cos_angle = b.dot(b_old);
        if(cos_angle > 1-eps){
            i= num_iter+1;
        }
    }

   (1)  double eigenvalue = (b.transpose() * X * b)/(b.transpose().dot(b));

   (2)  double eigenvalue2 = b.transpose() * X * b;
    eigenvalue2 = eigenvalue2/b.transpose().dot(b);

    return make_pair(eigenvalue, b / b.norm());
}
```

Comment: Does this work? `double eigenvalue = static_cast<double>(b.transpose() * X * b)/(b.transpose().dot(b));`

Comment: yes it does, thank you! SO it seems that I need to cast to double before dividing. That seems to be the reason :)

Comment: Great, I had to verify because I wasn't sure what `b.transpose() * X * b` returned, but it seems to be a matrix or a higher rank type defined by Eigen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen distinguishes between 1x1 matrices and scalars, e.g., `b.transpose()*b` is actually a 1x1 matrix. There are some special cases where products resulting in a 1x1 matrix are implicitly convertible to a scalar, but the preferred way is to always use `a.dot(b)` for these products (if indeed you want to have a scalar).

Moreover `b.tranpose().dot(b)` is actually the same as just `b.dot(b)` or just `b.squaredNorm()` (the latter might be slightly faster, since `b` needs to be read only once, although compilers are often smart enough to optimize both to the same assembly code).

Overall, I suggest using this notation:

```
double eigenvalue = b.dot(X * b) / b.squaredNorm();
// or:
double eigenvalue = (b.transpose()*X).dot(b) / b.squaredNorm();
```

Answer (score 1):

In (2), when you assign the former expression first, it triggers an implicit conversion to double since the variable to which it's assigned to is a double.
In (1), the former expression is first evaluated which seems to be of a type of a higher rank defined by the Eigen library, and the later `double` expression (the dot product) cannot be promoted to this type, hence the error.
If you tell the compiler explicitly that you want `b.transpose() * X * b` to be reduced to a double, it will work:

```
double eigenvalue = static_cast<double>(b.transpose() * X * b)/(b.transpose().dot(b));
```